# Serialize a custom class in a custom inspector in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I need to serialize a class in a custom inspector (using visually the Editor) like as doing in a Monobehaviour script like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CustomClass
{
 int myInt
}
```

```
public class OtherClass : MonoBehaviour
{
 [SerializeField] CustomClass customClass;
}
```

which gives this result:
[result wanted and given using the code above, where DamageEffect = CustomClass and Damage = myInt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P81LE.png)

In my custom editor, I'd like something like this:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CardObject))]
class AnotherClassEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        [SerializeField] CustomClass customclass;                        
    }
}
```

but, as expected, it points out an error.

I also tried with `EditorGUILayout.ObjectField()` but I haven't been able to, I'm not so experienced so please try to keep the answers simple.

Actually, I need this serialization to happen only when an enum is equal to a certain value, the overall script is something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Card", menuName = "CardObject")]
public class CardObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<CardEffectType> effectsTypes;
    //other...
    [HideInInspector] public List<CardEffect> effects;

    //other...
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(CardObject))]
class CardObjectEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        CardObject cardObject = (CardObject)target;

        foreach(CardEffectType effectType in cardObject.effectsTypes)
        {
            switch (effectType)
            {
                case CardEffectType.DamageEffect:
                    {
                        //!!!
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif

public enum CardEffectType
{
    DamageEffect, //other...
}
```

I found some workarounds but the result is not as when a class is serialized in a Monobehaviour.

Comment: Place your CustomClass declaration outside of the OnInspectorGUI function, but still inside the class.

Comment: sorry, I edited my question to be more precise, do you think your answer could still solve the problem, if so, precisely, where should I write my CustomClass(DamageEffect)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking for.  What do you mean by " I need this serialization to happen only when an enum is equal to a certain value"?

Comment: In my inspector I have a variable of type effect(which is an enum) and based on the value(Idk whether is "value" the correct word) assigned to this enum through the inspector, I'd like to show and then serialize the class associated to that value. As the example, if the enum is equal to DamageEffect, then the inspector should display and let me serialize an object of type DamageEffect(for convenience I named the enum values and the class the same)

Comment: Where are you serializing the value to?  Are you putting the object into the effects list?  If so, you need to loop through all the effects and display each one (or create a temp variable to serialize the value to).  You can create editors by type using Editor.CreateEditor.  You do not want to do that in inspector gui, likely in OnEnable and cache them in a dictionary<Type, Editor>.

Comment: The objects are stored in the effects list through a foreach loop, but the list is of type 'CardEffect' which all the effects like 'DamageEffect' inherit from, so in the inspector I can see there is an element, but I can't serialize it. What do you mean by "You can create editors by type using Editor.CreateEditor.", what would I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to show something like how Unity would, you can use `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField()`, but it asks for a `SerializedProperty`, what you need to get from the `SerializedObject`, not from the actual target. Something like this:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyType))]
public class MyTypeEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _variableIWantToShow;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _variableIWantToShow = serializedObject.FindProperty("<name-of-the-variable>");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // ...
        if (ShowVariable) EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_variableIWantToShow);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can manage collections (array, list, etc.) as `SerializedProperty`, but it adds some complexity.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html
https://answers.unity.com/questions/682932/using-generic-list-with-serializedproperty-inspect.html

Comment: But doing so, I should store in every 'SerializedObject' an instance of all the possible classes I'd like to serialize, correct me if I'm wrong. This doesn't seem so good in terms of performance, is this the only alternative I have?

Comment: You can make a string array with the variables you want to control, and let Unity draw the rest with `DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject, <serialized object array>);`

I used to declare the second parameter like that:

`private static readonly string[] _baseProperties = new string[] { "m_Script", "xy", "xz", };`

m_Script is Unity's default field for the script itself at the very top of (almost) every component.

Comment: I'm grateful, but this seems a little too complicated for me, if there isn't any simpler solution, I'll go for some crappy workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your int myInt public, or add [SerializeField] attribute to it - inspector is only designed to work with serialisable fields (public fields are serialised by default in unity editor), currently your myInt is private hence only visible from within

As mentioned in an answer by h4i, proper way to display objects in the editor is using SerializedProperty, casting 'target' seems like a good idea at start but is only useful if you want to call methods on the object, it will fail in several other cases.

What you may want to consider is declaring a PropertyDrawer while Editors service a single monobehaviour type, a PropertyDrawer handles displaying every instance of a serializable class, and will be used every time a default editor uses a PropertyField internally. This will probably match your use case better

Comment: Thanks, but this would let me modify through the inspector only the property and not the entire class, am I wrong?

Comment: Actually in the script myInt is public, but still, I can't figure out how to use it correctly with SerializedProprty. As I intended I should declare an object of type SerializedProperty, then assign it to myInt to FIndProperty, but this requires an object of type Serialized object, how can I achieve this?

Comment: PropertyField works recursively, if a properety consists of other properties, their respective editors / drawers will also be drawn. serializedObject is inherited in Editor class, you get it automatically. Also, while at it, what you actually want to do is to declare a PropertyDrawer for your class, then it will be used even in default (not declared) editors that have your class as a public/serialized field